# Free graphic equalizer for Windows Media Player 12

Tags: windows-media-player, equalizer

We recently moved to 64 bit Windows-7 machines at work. The bundled version of Windows Media Player doesn't have a graphic equaliser.

Does anyone know of a free (I'm not paying for anything I install in work) equaliser that is unobtrusive (i.e. not adware) and won't constantly suggest that I "Upgrade" to the premium edition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Start Windows Media Player 12 in Library View
2. Now press Alt to get the menu, and navigate to View> Skin Chooser.
3. Select ‘Revert’ skin from the skins list and press the “Apply Button” button.
4. You can now see the “Graphic Equalizer” button at the bottom right of the skinned WMP12.
5. Lastly, set the default equalizer options to whatever you like.

Comment: Dude, +1. I didn't have enough rep to +1 when I accepted your answer. Thanks again mate.

Answer (score 1):

The graphic equalizer is not visible in the library mode(the default mode for Windows media player 12 in Windows 7 xx-bit). You must be in the skin mode to access the graphic equalizer or switch to the now playing mode(click on the little squares tab in the lower right corner of the default Windows media player to get to now playing window). The graphic equalizer is selectable from the media player skin you choose or the now playing Windows media player window by right clicking inside the window or from a selectable drop down tab. How the Windows Media Player works in Windows 7 xx-bit is fully described here: [Windows Media Player 12](http://Windows.Microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/Windows-media-player-12)

If you want a free graphic equalizer program try the Audacity audio mix/record software suite. For Windows 7 xx-bit use the 1.3.12 beta version.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)? It supports an amazing number of formats, and has a built-in graphic equalizer, and is 100% free. I've got it working on Vista 64-bit, and I would imagine it works just as well on your Windows 7 64-bit.